# Erro 1062: error in SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I have three tables. t1,t2,t3. I want to get the common values between t2,t3 and select the whole record from t1. When I type my statement as in:

```
select * from db.t1 where col1 
IN (
select col1 from t2 , t3
where t2.col1=t3.col1);
```

I get a syntax error. What is wrong ?

Comment: what database platform are you using? error numbers vary by platform. also looks like you have your alias names backward. have you tried 'select t2.col1 from t2 , t3 where t2.col1=t3.col1' for your interior select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're testing that t2.col1=t3.col1 (instead of col1.t2=col1.t3, as shown), then one other problem is the ambiguity for col1 in the inner SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
where col1.t2=col1.t3);
```

Should be:

```
where t2.col1=t3.col1);
```

Comment: Sorry this was just a typing mistake here. But I wrote it as you did. I edited my post. The problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe you have to rename your encapsulated col1 :

```
select * from db.t1 where t1.col1 
IN (
select col1 as col1bis from t2 , t3
where t2.col1 = t3.col1);
```